# Enlarged, blue registered trademark symbol in Gmail for iPhone in iOS 10

Tags: responsive-design, gmail, html-email, ios10

I'm building a responsive email message, and it's rendering well in every email client except for Gmail for iPhone 6 and 6+, using iOS 10. The only thing that's going wrong is that the registered trademark and copyright symbols in the message are appearing many font sizes larger and in a blue color, when they're supposed to be gray (#646464), 9px high, with a vertical-align property of 3px.

EMAIL_PRTNR_NAME in the code snippet represents a JavaScript variable which pulls in a brand name with a registered trademark in it.

I'm using the a[x-apple-data-detectors] style in the CSS, although the registered trademarks and copyright symbols are not linked to anything.

Has this happened to anyone before? Any ideas on how to fix?

Thank you in advance!

[enlarged, blue registered trademark symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQh52.png)

```html
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="24" class="mobileHide">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="353" valign="middle" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; color:#646464; font-size:16px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height:22px;">
      <div style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; height:6px; font-size:6px; line-height:6px;">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <table width="353" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="353" valign="middle" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; color:#646464; font-size:16px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height:22px;"><span style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; color:#646464; font-size:16px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height:22px;">FULL_NAME</span><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="353" valign="middle" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; color:#646464; font-size:13px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height:22px;"><span style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; color:#646464; font-size:13px; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height:22px;">EMAIL_PRTNR_NAME</span><br></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div style="height:6px; font-size:6px; line-height:6px;">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if you posted the actual code involved so we could see the problem? Is it a state secret or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Google fixed it - have been tested and looks OK for `&reg;` and `&trade;`

Answer (score 2):

©

```
<span style="line-height: 15px; vertical-align: 4px; font-size:12px;">&#9400;</span>
```

®

```
<span style="line-height: 15px; vertical-align: 4px; font-size:13px;">&#9415;</span>
```

™

```
<span style="line-height: 12px; vertical-align: 7px; font-size:8px;">TM</span>
```

```html
<span style="line-height: 15px; vertical-align: 4px; font-size:12px;">&#9400;</span>
<span style="line-height: 15px; vertical-align: 4px; font-size:13px;">&#9415;</span>
<span style="line-height: 12px; vertical-align: 7px; font-size:8px;">TM</span>
```

Comment: This code substitution appears to work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing a similar issue where google is replacing it with their 'goomoji' that is rendering with incorrect styling. I believe this is a bug in gmail and will fix itself.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem with a few of my Mailchimp templates, and only in combination with GMail. So either a bug, or someone at Google trying to be funny :)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid Enlarged registered symbol in gmail and Outlook use this code.


©
<!--[if gte mso 9]>&#169; <![endif]--> <!--[if !mso]><!--> &#9400;<!--<![endif]-->

®
<!--[if gte mso 9]><span style="font-size: 55%; line-height: 0px; vertical-align: 4px;">&#174;</span> <![endif]--><!--[if !mso]><!--><span style="font-size: 55%; line-height: 0px; vertical-align: 4px;">&#9415;</span><!--<![endif]-->

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem in Gmail, unfortunately.